# Передача php данных на JS

Tags: php, javascript

Есть соц.сеть, в ней  надо будет отображать, через JS, свое имя, фамилию, аватар и т.п. Данные о себе получаю при открытии страницы. Вопрос: можно ли как-то передать эти данные взяты в PHP, в JS скрипт, без AJAX и DOM, как делают это другие соц.сети?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно через cookie. Для удобства используйте плагин [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Простейший пример:

**PHP**

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['name'])){
    setcookie('name', 'Zow');
}
```

**JS**

```
var cookieParams = $.cookie('name');
if(cookieParams){
    console.log(cookieParams); // Zow
}
```

Comment: а соц.сети именно так поступают?

Comment: @Zow, скажу честно - они мне не докладывали )) Но вот то, что многие соц.сети используют ajax - это точно.

Answer (score 1):

PHP

```
$data = array('name' => 'Вася', 'secondname' => 'Пупкин');
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var data = <?php json_encode($data) ?>;
for(key in data) {
    console.log(key, data[key]);
}

</script>
```